# Issue understanding NSDateFormatter's .dateFormat options?

Tags: ios, swift

Are there any layman's references or tutorials for these date formats?

Here's the code I'm working on:

```
  if let publishDate = json["publishDate"] as? String {

        // publishDate is: "2015-04-14T18:34:46.001Z"
        var dateString = publishDate
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS.000Z"
        var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
        let ago = date!.timeAgo
        println(ago)

    }
```

Any tips on solving these kind of problems would be appreciated!

Comment: Apple's "Introduction to Data Formatting Programming Guide For Cocoa" has a chapter "Date Formatters" with links to the relevant Unicode Date Formatters reference. There is also a "Date and Time Programming Guide".

Comment: In short, if going from ISO8601/RFC3339 date string in that format to `NSDate` object, you want to use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` (I assume you meant colons and not dashes in the time portion). Note, the capitalization is very important. Also, to make sure this works for international users, don't forget to set the `locale` of the `NSDateFormatter` to `NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US_POSIX")` as described in [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Hey Rob, yea I got that and added it the an extension, and it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Data Formatting Guide: Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) has links that describe how to interpret the `dateFormat` strings.

I'm inferring from your question, though, that you're dealing with a ISO 8601/RFC 3339 date string. In that case, I'd also draw your attention to Apple's [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html) which provides to guidance on dealing with these date strings for international users (specifically, make sure to set `locale` of the `NSDateFormatter` in case the end-user's device isn't using Gregorian calendar).

Anyway, it probably should look something like:

```
let dateString = "2015-04-14T17:12:12.123Z"

let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

This formatter can be used for converting to and from ISO 8601/RFC 3339 date strings.